# Ableton Push Start/Stop with a Sustain Pedal

Tags: ableton-live, production, keyboard-pedals

MacBook Pro (Big Sur 11.5.2)
Ableton Intro
Ableton Push 2
OnStage KSP20 (the sustain pedal)

Is there a way to get an Ableton Push 2 to play/stop via a foot pedal? My sister has a gig in a few days and she wants to start/stop her Ableton tracks with a foot pedal on stage. The OnStage KSP20 is  a binary switch meaning it clicked on or off. It's not a rolling sustain like real sustain pedals. When she plugs it into the second input on the back of the Ableton Push 2 it record enables the push and when she double clicks it, it  creates a new track. Is there a way to get this pedal to start/stop the playback instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set MIDI remote control mapping:

- Connect the pedal to the second pedal input
- Open Ableton Live and go to Preferences and select MIDI
- Turn on the Track and Remote
- Control Surface: Ableton Push 2
- Input: select the pedal
- Click MIDI button in the top right corner of the screen
- Press the pedal, highlighting MIDI CC
- Double-click the MIDI CC option and select Play/Stop from
- Click MIDI button again.